# Isomorphism to the group of all infinite binary sequences.

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

The following question is Question 12.4 from Abstract Algebra by Dan Saracino.

Suppose $G=Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2 \times \cdots $, where $Z_2$  is the additive group of integers modulo 2.

How to prove or disprove that $G$ is isomorphic to $G \times G$?

---

This is  my attempt:

I have tried to find a function which is an isomorphism.

If $\phi(x)=(x,x)$, then $$\phi(a+b)=(a+b,a+b)=(a,a)+(b,b)=\phi(a) \circ \phi(b)$$

Also, $a\ne b$ implies $(a,a) \ne(b,b)$ and so $\phi(a) \ne \phi(b)$.

Now, I do not know how to prove this function is onto.

I also do not know if we consider $x=(x_1,x_2, \cdots)$, whether $(x,x)$ is well defined or not.

Comment: That map is definitely not onto. It might help to forget about groups and think about a simpler problem: can you find a bijection $X \to X \times X$ where $X = \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \times \cdots$?  How can you split a sequence into two pieces?

Comment: I don't think your isomorphism works... have you tried looking at interlacing: $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)\leftrightarrow (x_1,x_3,x_5,\ldots)\times (x_2,x_4,x_6,\ldots)$?

Comment: For me it is unclear whether $Z_2 \times Z_2 \times \cdots$ denotes a restricted or an unrestricted direct product. The assumption in the comments seems to be that it is unrestricted.

Comment: @DerekHolt I do not know the definition of restricted or unrestricted direct product. In the assumption of the question, there is a sentence that may help. It says that "one copy of $Z_2$ for each positive integer."

Comment: No that doesn't help! In the restricted direct product, all but finitely many components of an element must equal the identity element. In the unrestricted direct product there is no such restriction.